# PHP Post Method Error

Tags: php, html, post

I am using Post method in my website. In my index.html file is the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title>Heater Login</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="login.php" class="login">
<p>
<label for="login">Username:</label>
<input type="text" name="login" id="login" value="John Appleseed">
</p>

<p>
<label for="password">Password:</label>
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="4815162342">
</p>

<p class="login-submit">
<button type="submit" class="login-button">Login</button>
</p>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

And in my login.php file is the following code:

```
<?php
echo($_POST['login']);
echo($_POST['password']);
?>
```

When I open html file, enter my credentials, click submit button it goes to php file end there's nothing.

Comment: How would that help, @Fred-ii-?

Comment: Can you print the output from :
var_dump($_POST);

Comment: I just noticed that now. Duh lol @AmalMurali

Comment: To: `OP`. There is nothing wrong with your code. Something is obviously wrong on your end  and could be a number of things. This is obviously NOT full code.

Comment: HI it is working fine on my machine

Comment: It's questions like these that open up the proverbial **"can of worms"**

Comment: Try changing your `action` attribute to `action="/login.php"`. Hopefully, that'll fix your issue.

Comment: @AmalMurali If the URL were wrong he'd get a `404` error.

Comment: @AmalMurali, He doesn't need to change anything. It works fine. Seems like PHP is not configured ? O.o

Comment: If you go to the Network tab of Developer Tools, do you see any errors next to `login.php`?

Comment: @Barmar: Okay, to test my theory, I just created a new file `test.php`, with the HTML markup (without changing anything), and then created another file `login.php` in the same directory, with just `<?php print_r($_POST); ?>`. After clicking on the submit button, the URL in the address bar changed to `http://localhost/test.php/login.php`. Changing the `action` attribute to `/login.php` **fixed** the issue.

Comment: check your address bar after pressing submit, check if thats exactly like @AmalMurali said. May be thats the problem.

Comment: @AmalMurali Your server must be doing some rewriting and redirecting. That should only happen if the URL of the form is `http://localhost/test.php/` with an extra `/` at the end.

Comment: A URL with no path prefix should be resolved to the same directory as the current URL.

Comment: @Barmar: You're right. The trailing slash was the culprit. As per my understanding, relative URLs resolve to the absolute ones based on the current script/document's URL. So, wouldn't changing the `action` attribute to `/login.php` make it work regardless of whether the trailing slash exists or not?

Comment: That would only work if the original page was `/index.html`. If the original page is `/path/to/index.html` then you would have to make the action `/path/to/login.php`.

Comment: Using relative URLs makes it easy to move things around as a group without having to update the URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you change this line of code with the new one Hope it will work

```
<button type="submit" class="login-button">Login</button>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
```

And last I want that you copy whole code from the stackoverflow  and use this code.Some times space may create a problem.

Comment: They're both the same and *will* submit the form. A `<button>` with `type` as `submit` is the same as an `<input>` with type set as `submit` (except for some bugs with some IE versions).

Answer (score -1):

This problem occurs when you directly open from its file location try opening file from server
like if you're using xampp  open localhost and then try.

Comment: `then try` can you be more specific?